# How to make a signal handler kill IPC's created with IPC_PRIVATE

Tags: c, signals, ipc

I have a main function that creates some semaphores and message queues specifying `IPC_PRIVATE` as the key. Now I need to handle the signal `SIGTERM` to kill all the IPCs before exit. The problem is that the function that removes the IPCs needs the IPCsID, and `sigaction` does not let me to pass any parameters apart from `signum`.
So how can I assign the function to `SIGTERM`?
I can't create global variables because the IPCs needs to be `IPC_PRIVATE`.

Comment: You should probably simply set a flag in the signal handler. Then, your main loop which has all the necessary info can clean up the semaphores.

Comment: None of the Sys V IPC functions can safely be used in signal handlers, btw.